# PHPのnumber_format関数の第1引数はfloat型ですか？ int型でもよいですか？ 戻り値はstring型ですか？

Tags: php

質問
・PHPのnumber_format関数の第1引数はfloat型ですか？
・number_format関数の第1引数はint型でもよいですか？
・戻り値はstring型ですか？
※戻り値については「フォーマットした結果を返します」としか書かれていないので、自分が試した結果のstring型以外が返ることがあるか知りたい

試したこと
[PHP: number_format - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.number-format.php)を見ると、第1引数には、floatと書かれていますが、1 を渡すと、string型の "1"が返ってきます。

```
var_dump(number_format(1)); //string(1) "1"
```

生じた疑問
・第一引数の欄にfloatと書かれているけど、なぜ引数に1を渡してエラーにならないの？
・1はint型ではないの？
・もしかすると、int型はfloat型に含まれるの？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ・PHPのnumber_format関数の第1引数はfloat型ですか？

はい。
リファレンスの第一引数が`float $num`と記載されている通りfloat型です。

> ・number_format関数の第1引数はint型でもよいですか？

はい。
PHPはコンテクストに応じて自動的に[型の相互変換](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.types.type-juggling.php)を行います。
例えばint型の`1`はfloat型の`1.0`に変更できるので、PHPの引数の型がfloat型の場合にもint型の数値を渡すことができます。

> ・戻り値はstring型ですか？

はい。
リファレンスの戻り値が`): string`となっている通り、string型を返します。
数値を人間の目で見やすいように整形(フォーマット)した文字列に変換するのが`number_format`の機能です。

```
print(number_format(1234567)); // 1,234,567
```

**参考資料**

- [PHPのsqrt関数で引数に整数型を渡しても処理されるのはなぜか](https://teratail.com/questions/177400)

Comment: 「PHPの引数の型がfloat型の場合にもint型の数値を渡すことができます」初めて知りました。参考になりました。「リファレンスの戻り値が): stringとなっている通り、string型を返します」ドキュメントには戻り値の型も掲載されているのですね。改めて確認してみて初めて気が付きました……